# Solving Coupled nonlinear Differential Equations For Eigenvalue And Eigen functions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method, physics, nonlinear

I tried to solve coupled nonlinear differential equations from this paper https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1016/j.jcp.2019.109058 to see eigenvalues and eigenfunctions in different dimensions. At first, I tried to solve it in 1D following the algorithm mentioned on pages 11 and 12 of the paper in the matrix method. But it did not work. Then I tried
NDEigensystem method.It did not work as well. Here is the problem statement
[image]
[image]

I like to generate the figures of u and v in different dimensions as
[image]

Another algorithm to solve this kind of equation is given in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.01244.pdf but in FORTRAN.

```
(*program in matrix method*)
\[Phi][n_, x_] := 
  1/Sqrt[2^2 n!] \[Pi]^(-1/4) Exp[-x^2/2] HermiteH[n, x];

b = 10; a = -10; m = 5;
h = (b - a)/m; xgrid = Table[a + j h, {j, 1, m - 1}];

v[x_] := 0.5 \[Omega] x^2;
\[Beta] = 1; \[Omega] = 0.1; \[Mu] = 0.1;
d2dx[n_] := 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> -2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, 
     Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {n, n}]/(1/h^2);
nonlin = SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> 
    2 \[Beta] Abs[\[Phi][1, xgrid[[i]]]]^2 - \[Mu], 
   Length[xgrid] {1, 1}];
pot = SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> v[xgrid[[i]]], Length[xgrid] {1, 1}];
Ah[n_] := d2dx[n] + nonlin + pot;
Bh = SparseArray[{i_, i_} :> - \[Beta] Abs[\[Phi][1, xgrid[[i]]]]^2, 
   Length[xgrid] {1, 1}];
BDG[n_] := MatrixForm[ArrayFlatten[{{Ah[n], Bh}, {-Bh, -Ah[n]}}]];
{vals, funcs} = Eigensystem[N[BDG[m - 1]], 4, Method -> "Arnoldi"]


(*NDEigensystem method*)
\[Omega] = 0.1; \[Beta] = 100;
{gvals, gfuns} = 
  NDEigensystem[-0.5 Laplacian[\[Phi][x], {x}] + 
    0.5*\[Omega]^2 x^2 \[Phi][x] + \[Beta]  Abs[\[Phi][x]]^2 \[Phi][
      x]  , \[Phi][x], {x, -10, 10}, 4, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05}}}}];

\[Mu]g = gval[[1]]; \[Phi]g = gfuns[[1]];

{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{ -0.5 Laplacian[vl[x], {x}] + 
    0.5 \[Omega]^2 x^2 vl[x] + 
    2 \[Beta] Abs[\[Phi]g[x]]^2 vl[x] - \[Mu]g vl[
      x] - \[Beta] \[Phi]g[x]^2 ul[x], -0.5 Laplacian[ul[x], {x}] + 
    0.5 \[Omega]^2 x^2  ul[x] + 
    2 \[Beta] Abs[\[Phi]g[x]]^2 ul[x] - \[Mu]g vl[
      x] - \[Beta] \[Phi]g[x]^2 ul[x], 
   DirichletCondition[ul[x] == 0, x == 10 || x == -10], 
   DirichletCondition[vl[x] == 0, x == 10 || x == -10]}, {ul[x], 
   vl[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 4, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> "MethodOfLines"}]
```

Comment: I am afraid that complex problems of this kind are ill-suited for this forum. Please run single lines at a time, read every message that shows up and try to understand what the problem is. If you cannot solve it, find a maximally simple example that gives that error, and then that may give a question suitable for this forum. Main problem with your `{gvals, gfuns} = NDEigensystem[...` is that the expression is *not linear* in `\[Phi]`. Also, stick to default methods unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I did notice something strange, a simple example is `f[_,_]:=Abort[]; NDEigensystem[f''[x],f[x],{x,-1,1},1]` which leads to an abort in V12.3, which I find surprising (anyone?). For this reason, I suggest you drop the `\[Phi][n_,x_]:=...` definition in your code, do not forget to clear old definitions or restart your kernel, and perhaps use another name for it that does not interfere with the function `\[Phi]` in your `NDEigensystem`.

Comment: There is no chance to use `NDEigensystem` since problem is nonlinear any way due to constraint $\int {(u^2-v^2)dx=1}$. I think that we can try to solve nonlinear problem with using `NMinimize` to optimize energy.

Comment: If not with the NDEigensystem @AlexTrounev then can it be solved through the Matrix method as mentioned in the papers https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1016/j.jcp.2019.109058 (pages 11 and 12)   and 
 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.01244.pdf  in Mathematica?

Comment: I don't understand methods described in the paper "Numerical methods for Bogoliubov-de Gennes excitations of Bose-Einstein condensates". Why they used normalization $\int {(u^2-v^2)}dx=1$, while there is a ground state with the same normalization and $u, v$ are small excitations over the ground state? Please, pay attention that in a linear case for $\beta=0, \omega_x=1$ they compute energy for oscillator as $\omega_i = 1, 2, 3, 4, ...$ (see Example 1, Case 1), but it should be $\omega_i = 1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 7/2, ... $.

Comment: Maybe your answer @AlexTrounev lies in the statement of  Lemma 2.4 point(1) on page 7 for beta=0 and for beta not equal to zero see the statement of Lemma 2.5 on the same page. They give expected theoretical omega values.

Comment: @ArghaDebnath Ah, I see, that these excitations are not really small excitations, but something as a mixture of states.  Nevertheless, they have been derived as small excitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As initial step to compute ground state we can use LDG method as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Get["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"];

L = 10; \[Beta] = 100; \[Omega] = 1; muTF = 
 1/2 (3 \[Omega] \[Beta]/2)^(2/3);
f = {2 (- mu p[t] + 1/2*\[Omega]^2 t^2 p[t] + \[Beta] p[t]^2 p[t]), 
  v[t]}; ini = {0, b1}; bc1 = 0;
LDGODEs[M0_, nn_, ns_, np_, f_, ini_, tmax_, tmin_] := 
 Module[{dx = (tmax - tmin)/nn,   A = Array[a, {M0 + 1, nn, 2}]}, 
  xl = Table[tmin + l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; UT[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
  psi[m_, k_, t_] := 
   Piecewise[{{UT[
       m, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
      xl[[k]] <= t <= xl[[k + 1]]}, {0, True}}];
  g = Table[
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, xl[[i]], xl[[i + 1]]], {i, nn}];
  dp = Table[
    D[UT[m, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
     t], {k, nn}];
  rul = {p[t] -> 
     Sum[a[m, k, 2] psi[m - 1, k, t], {m, 1, M0 + 1}, {k, 1, nn}], 
    v[t] -> Sum[
      a[m, k, 1] psi[m - 1, k, t], {m, 1, M0 + 1}, {k, 1, nn}]};
  eq = Flatten[
    Table[-Sum[
         a[i + 1, n, 
           ks] (Table[(psi[i, n, t] If[j == 0, 0, 
                dp[[n]] /. m -> j]), {t, g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . 
            g[[n]][[All, 2]]), {i, 0, 
          M0}] - (Table[(f[[ks]] /. rul) psi[j, n, t], {t, 
           g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . g[[n]][[All, 2]]), {j, 0, M0}, {n, 1, 
       nn}, {ks, 1, 2}] + 
     Table[Sum[
        a[i + 1, n, 
          ks] (psi[i, n, xl[[n + 1]]] psi[j, n, xl[[n + 1]]]), {i, 0, 
         M0}] - Sum[
        If[n < 2, ini[[ks]]/(M0 + 1), 
          a[i + 1, n - 1, ks] psi[i, n - 1, xl[[n]]]] psi[j, n, 
          xl[[n]]], {i, 0, M0}], {j, 0, M0}, {n, 1, nn}, {ks, 
       2 ns}]];
  eq1 = (p[t] - bc1) /. rul /. t -> tmax;
  eqn = Join[eq, {eq1}];
  var = Join[Flatten[A], {b1, mu}]; 
  energy = 
   Sum[Table[((1/2 v[t]^2 + 
          1/2 \[Omega]^2 t^2 p[t]^2 + \[Beta]/2 p[t]^4) /. rul), {t, 
       g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . g[[n]][[All, 2]], {n, 1, nn}]; 
  norm = Sum[
     Table[(( p[t]^2) /. rul), {t, g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . 
      g[[n]][[All, 2]], {n, 1, nn}] == 1/2; 
  con = Join[{norm}, Table[eqn[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqn]}]];
  sol1 = NMinimize[{energy, con}, var]; sol1]
```

Solution

```
M0 = 2; nn = 10; ns = 1; np = 5; tmax = L; tmin = 0; 
 ldgsol = 
  LDGODEs[M0, nn, ns, np, f, ini, tmax, tmin]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Please note, that we minimize energy to compute $\mu _g$, Finally we have

```
mu /. sol1[[2]]

Out[]= 14.1341
```

This value we can compare to theoretical value `muTF = 14.1155`. Wave function we should extend on $-L\le x\le L$ as

```
lst = Table[{t, 
    Evaluate[
     Sum[a[i + 1, k, 2] psi[i, k, Abs[t]], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] /. 
      sol1[[2]]]}, {t, -L, L, .0101}];

\[Phi]g = Interpolation[Join[lst, {{10, 0}}], InterpolationOrder -> 4];
```

Compare this function with theoretical one (red line)

```
Show[Plot[\[Phi]g[x], {x, -L, L}], 
 Plot[If[muTF > x^2/2, Sqrt[(muTF - x^2/2)/100], 0], {x, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Using LDG method we can compute several excitations, but problem is correct on $-\infty <x<\infty$ only, while on limited interval we have some mixture of states. For example

```
 ns = 2;μg=mu/.sol1[[2]]; x1[t_] = Table[Symbol["x1" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, ns}]; 
v1[t_] = 
 Table[Symbol["v1" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, 1, ns}]; bc = {0, 0}; f1 = 
 Join[{2 (0.5 \[Omega]^2 x^2 vl[x] + 
        2 \[Beta] Abs[\[Phi]g[x]]^2 vl[x] - \[Mu]g vl[
          x] - \[Beta] \[Phi]g[x]^2 ul[x] + mu1 vl[x]), 
     2 (0.5 \[Omega]^2 x^2 ul[x] + 
        2 \[Beta] Abs[\[Phi]g[x]]^2 ul[x] - \[Mu]g ul[
          x] - \[Beta] \[Phi]g[x]^2 vl[x] - mu1 ul[x])} /. {ul[x] -> 
      x11[t], vl[x] -> x12[t], \[Phi]g[x] -> 
      If[Abs[t] <= L, \[Phi]g[t], 0]} /. x -> t, v1[t]]; 
LDGODE[M0_, nn_, ns_, np_, f_, ini_, tmax_, tmin_] := 
 Module[{dx = (tmax - tmin)/nn,   A = Array[a, {M0 + 1, nn, 2 ns}]}, 
  xl = Table[tmin + l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; 
  UT[m_, t_] := BernoulliB[m, t];
  psi[m_, k_, t_] := 
   Piecewise[{{UT[
       m, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
      xl[[k]] <= t <= xl[[k + 1]]}, {0, True}}];
  g = Table[
    GaussianQuadratureWeights[np, xl[[i]], xl[[i + 1]]], {i, nn}];
  dp = Table[
    D[UT[m, (2 t - xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])/(xl[[k + 1]] - xl[[k]])], 
     t], {k, nn}];
  rul1 = 
   Join[Table[
     x1[t][[i]] -> 
      Sum[a[m, k, i + ns] psi[m - 1, k, t], {m, 1, M0 + 1}, {k, 1, 
        nn}], {i, ns}], 
    Table[v1[t][[i]] -> 
      Sum[a[m, k, i] psi[m - 1, k, t], {m, 1, M0 + 1}, {k, 1, 
        nn}], {i, 1, ns}]];
  eq = Flatten[
    Table[-Sum[
         a[i + 1, n, 
           ks] (Table[(psi[i, n, t] If[j == 0, 0, 
                dp[[n]] /. m -> j]), {t, g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . 
            g[[n]][[All, 2]]), {i, 0, 
          M0}] - (Table[(f[[ks]] /. rul1) psi[j, n, t], {t, 
           g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . g[[n]][[All, 2]]), {j, 0, M0}, {n, 1, 
       nn}, {ks, 2 ns}] + 
     Table[Sum[
        a[i + 1, n, 
          ks] (psi[i, n, xl[[n + 1]]] psi[j, n, xl[[n + 1]]]), {i, 0, 
         M0}] - Sum[
        If[n < 2, ini[[ks]]/(M0 + 1), 
          a[i + 1, n - 1, ks] psi[i, n - 1, xl[[n]]]] psi[j, n, 
          xl[[n]]], {i, 0, M0}], {j, 0, M0}, {n, 1, nn}, {ks, 
       2 ns}]];
  eqb = {(x1[t][[1]] - bc[[1]]), x1[t][[2]] - bc[[2]]} /. rul1 /. 
    t -> tmax;
  
  var = Join[Flatten[A], {b1, b2, mu1}]; 
  norm1 = {Sum[
      Table[(( x11[t]^2 - x12[t]^2) /. rul1), {t, 
         g[[n]][[All, 1]]}] . g[[n]][[All, 2]], {n, 1, nn}] == 1/2}; 
  eqn = Join[eq, eqb];
  sol2 = 
   FindRoot[Join[Table[eqn[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqn]}], norm1], 
    Table[{var[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[var]}]]; sol2];
```

Solution

```
ini = Join[{b1, b2}, {0, 0}]; M0 = 4; nn = 40; ns = 2; np = 5; 
 tmax = 9.9863; tmin = 0; 
 ldgsol2 = 
  LDGODE[M0, nn, ns, np, f1, ini, tmax, tmin]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

It should be first eigenvalue $\omega_1=1$, but we have instead

```
mu1 /. sol2

Out[]= 1.00091
```

Nevertheless, we have norm `2 norm1[[1, 1]] /. sol2` =1.
Theoretical solution for eigenfunction is given by

```
u0[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2] (x \[Phi]g[x] - \[Phi]g'[x]); 
v0[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2] (x \[Phi]g[x] + \[Phi]g'[x])
```

Numerical solution is

```
pl1 = Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[
    Sum[a[i + 1, k, s] psi[i, k, t], {i, 0, M0}, {k, nn}] /. 
     sol2], {t, tmin, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red}, 
   Exclusions -> None], {s, ns + 1, 2 ns}]
```

Compare to theory they look like

```
pl = {Plot[u0[x], {x, 0, Sqrt[2 muTF] - .07}], 
  Plot[v0[x], {x, 0, Sqrt[2 muTF] - .07}]}

Show[pl1, pl]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks, @AlexTrounev for this solution. When I ran this program. In the first part where you minimize energy to compute μg I am getting -0.163079 instead of 14.1341 and consequently, the resultant \phi_g profile is also different than posted one. In the second program, μg is not defined in f1.

Comment: I have many questions regarding the program @AlexTrounev. How f is defined mainly second part (v[t]) in {}. How the definition of \psi is working? Can you provide in short the algorithm in the eq part?

Comment: How can I get @AlexTrounev Other Eigenvalues and EigenFunctions?

Comment: @ArghaDebnath 1) I run first part of code and evaluate `mu /. sol1[[2]]` = 14.1341. Plot also looks same as above. Could you run again with a fresh kernel?   Please, don't run together first and second part. Run first part, compute $\mu g$ as `μg=mu/.sol1[[2]]`, and then run second part of code. 2) we solve first order ODEs. 3) With LDG method we can compute several modes.